# Order parent object list by child list attribute

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I want to sort an object list in C# by LINQ, I want to order this list by a child list with a certain attribute: The class structure based on nhibernate, all Attributes are public virtual.

```
ParentobjectsList.OrderBy(x => x.ChildobjectList.Attribute);
```

How can I achive this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like your structure is something like this:

```
class ChildObject
{
    public int Attribute { get; set; }
}

class ParentObject
{
    public IEnumerable<ChildObject> ChildobjectList { get; set; }
}
```

In this case it's not possible to simply order an `IEnumerable<ParentObject>` by the `ChildObject.Attribute` property, because there are potentially many values for each `ParentObject`. How is Linq going to know which value to use for the ordering? You'll have to use some kind of aggregate function. There are many options, but here are just a few:

- [`Max`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max.aspx) to sort by the largest element in `ChildobjectList`
- [`Min`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min.aspx) to sort by the smallest element in `ChildobjectList`
- [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx) to sort by the first item in the `ChildobjectList`
- [`Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx) to sort by the sum of values, assuming the type of `Attribute` can be summed

Precisely which one you use depends on your exact requirements. In any case you'll use it like this:

```
var result = 
    ParentobjectsList.OrderBy(x => x.ChildobjectList.Max(c => c.Attribute));
```